# MS ACCESS SQL Query on two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and am having trouble setting up this query. I have two tables, one which holds info about the teams, named TEAMS which looks like this:

**TEAMS**

```
Name|City|Attendance
Jets|  NY| 50
...
```

And the other which holds info about the games played, named GAMES:

**GAMES**

```
Home|Visitors|Date     |Result
Jets| Broncos| 1/1/2012| Tie
...
```

For each row in GAMES I am to give the name and city of each team (both home team and visiting team), the date and result of the game--a total of six fields.

Right now I have figured out how to display the fields but only in a way that gives one team's city, not both. Here is my query so far. I figure I need a subquery of some sort but can't figure out how to set it up. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT Home, City AS [Home City], Visitors, City AS [Visitor City], Date, Result
FROM GAMES, TEAMS
WHERE Home=Name
ORDER BY Home DESC , Result DESC , Visitors DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `TEAMS` table twice (and, while on it, instead of using *implicit* joins in the `where` condition, use *explicit* joins.. cleaner and easier to read):

```
select g.home, ht.city as home_city, 
       g.visitor, vt.city as visitor_city, 
       g.date, g.result
from (games as g
     inner join teams as ht on g.home = ht.name)
     inner join teams as vt on g.visitor = vt.name
```

I'm using aliases in this example for the tables to shorten the table names (`g` for `GAMES`, `ht` for "home team" and `vt` for "visitor team"). Notice that, instead of defining the relation conditions in the `where` clause, I'm defining it directly in the `from` clause (using `inner join`).

Comment: +1 for the overall design.  To make this work in Access SQL, he will need parentheses in the `FROM` clause.  Access requires them for a query which includes more than one `JOIN`.

Comment: @HansUp Really? (I'm kinda rusty with my "Bill'SQL", but I think that this will work anyway)

Comment: thanks this makes complete sense, but where would I put the parentheses? I've tried putting them in different spots but I get the error, "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'g.Home = ht.Name inner join  TEAMS as vt  on g.Visitor = vt.Name'.

Comment: If you set up the joins in the Access query designer it will include the parentheses where needed to keep the db engine happy.  I suspect the `FROM` clause should look like this: `from (games as g
     inner join teams as ht on g.home = ht.name)
     inner join teams as vt on g.visitor = vt.name`

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for the feedback. I've just edited the post to include the parenthesis as you suggest

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to figure it out a couple min before you, yours may work too however but I didnt try it. It looks like this: from (((GAMES as g
     inner join TEAMS as ht on g.Home = ht.Name)
     inner join TEAMS as vt on g.Visitors = vt.Name));

Comment: Access' SQL (which I like to call "Bill'SQL") has some quirks (and a sick love for parenthesis)... You'll have to take care of that when you write your queries. (By the way, if this was useful to you, up-vote it and/or accept it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **JOIN** the `TEAMS` table twice.

```
SELECT Home, HomeTeam.City as Home_City, Visitors, VisTeam.City AS Vis_City,
  -- more field
FROM GAMES JOIN TEAMS AS HomeTeam
ON GAMES.Home=HomeTeam.Name
   JOIN TEAMS AS VisTeam ON GAMES.Visitors=VisTeam.Name;
```